# How to get result by using np.histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a histogram by using `numpy.histogram`. What command should I use to get the histogram? Here is my code:

```
a = [1,2,1]
bins = [0,1,2,3]
```

Comment: That's not really code. Read the docs. You don't even need numpy in most cases (matplotlib already uses numpy for these calculations).

Comment: if i use conts,bins=np.histogram(a,bins). What else should i write after this to get histogram

Comment: As you want to plot it, read matplotlib's docs. Maybe you will recognize, that you do not need to do those calculations yourself. But you can. There are tons of examples within the official docs!

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: i can also use plt.hist() function but it is giving a value error that there are too many values to unpack

Comment: n,bi=plt.hist(data,bins=[0,10,20,30,40,60,80,90,100])
print n
print bin

Comment: I read about this error but couldn't get clear understanding of this.Can anyone please explain this by simple example

Comment: You get that error saying `to many values to unpack` because you are trying to store the 3 objects that `plt.hist` returns (`n, bins, patches`) into 2 variables `n, bi`. See [the pyplot docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html) for the return values of `plt.hist`.